# Get Data from AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, afnetworking

Since I am new to IOS and AFNetworking 3,0 is new, I don't know how to retrieve data from AFHTTPSessionManager.
I have to following message and I want to return the result

```
- (NSString *) makeServiceCall;
{
    NSString *response = @"";
    @try {

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        [manager
         POST:self.url.absoluteString
         parameters:self.parameters
         progress:nil
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id  responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);}
         failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *  task, NSError *  error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
        [AFHTTPSessionManager manager].securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `AFHTTPSessionManager POST:parameters:progress:success:failure:` is an asynchronous method.

What you are trying to do is return a string from the method calling it. This will not work as the method will finish before the download has started.

You need to call this with a completion block something like this...

```
- (void)getStringWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id))completion {
    NSLog(@"Method started");
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager
     POST:self.url.absoluteString
     parameters:self.parameters
     progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
         NSLog(@"Download underway");
     }
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id  responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Download successful");
         completion(responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *  task, NSError *  error) {
         NSLog(@"Error");
     }];

    // trying to return a string here won't work because the download hasn't finished yet.
    // You can see the order of things happening by adding logs...
    NSLog(@"Method finished");
}
```

The order of the logs in this code will be...

1. Method started
2. Method finished
3. Download underway
4. Download successful

As you can see, trying to return at the end of the method won't work because the download won't have completed yet.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question, I don't know what is the return type of the AFHTTPSessionManager, I just want the method to return the response of the request.

Comment: @HarounSMIDA did you not read my answer? You cannot do that. The download is asynchronous. It will not have downloaded the response before the method finishes.

Comment: @HarounSMIDA changed so now the completion block will accept any object type.

Comment: I am not doing any download thing. Just a post request

Comment: @HarounSMIDA ok, so where does the response come from? What response is it you want to return? Is it a response from a server that you are POSTing to?

Comment: Yes it's a response from a server that I am posting to, let's say it's a request for login, the response (JSON) will be either "status"="true or ="false".
How to retrieve that response and return it?

Comment: @HarounSMIDA ok, so the response is "downloaded" from the server. Whether it's a POST or a GET it's still downloading the response. Which is asynchronous and so you can't return the response from that method. The correct way to do it is to use a completion block like I have done in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't get how can I verify if the user successfully logged or not `"status" = "true"` or `"status" = "false"`

Comment: @HarounSMIDA make a completion block with a Boolean input that is true if the user logged in successfully. I have no idea what your server is returning so I have no idea how you should implement it. What you can't do is return the response from that method. You need to put the response into a completion block. That's what your question is. Nothing to do with verifying if a user logged in successfully.

Comment: Return When successfully logged in :
`{
  "user_id": "149",
  "status": "OK",
  "sessid": "NDPFZl7WTD76g_tKSEpS5x_2oSne3-0tve3xUSarQMU",
  "session_name": "SESS1340a18f7862a3c45d507e5c4c991509",
  "token": "XoLQx3e4B02SlRdEYZ0yCtGwY_7hZTN0zToHkLvzij4",
  "username": "haroun.smida",
  "email": "smida.haroun@gmail.com",
  "municipalite": "535d1e5712bdaa765acb82ed",
  "region": "535d1e5712bdaa765acb82e8"
}`

Comment: Return when wrong credentials :
`{
  "status": "NOK",
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect."
  }
}`

Comment: @HarounSMIDA so you know what the return is .You can then pass the relevant information into the completion block. I am not here to write your code. You asked a question, I answered it. Nothing in your question mentioned logging a user in etc... I think you should write a new question.